# Problem with cinnamon desktop icons

Tags: 16.04, icons, cinnamon, desktop-icons

I install cinnamon desktop environment in Ubuntu. Now i face a problem that some icons and file icons freezes as they are image files in the desktop. I am unable to move them or remove these icons from my desktop.

[image: Icon in cinnamon desktop]

Please help to resolve this problem.

*This problem occurs only in cinnamon desktop environment.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this problem?

Comment: I was not found any permanent solution. Solution was there but only for temporary basis.

Comment: Are gnome settings and Nautilus part of Cinnamon? If so I know a possible solution.

Comment: I was face this issue long time ago. Big changes are possible in last 3 years.  I suggest and request to post the possible solution.it can help to find idea for the solution of relevant experience

Comment: Can you please try disabling Desktop Icons Extension.
link: https://askubuntu.com/a/1173861/1565970

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hey there i didn't use cinnamon till now but commonly those problems will be solved by:

1. restarting your machine. (because of invalid cache)
2. changing the icon theme in settings. (changing in icon properties)

Comment: Is there any stable solution for this problem because this problem occurs again and again?